# How do I get a bash script to echo itself into a new file?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script. I want to have this script recreate itself in /usr/local/bin without needing an additional file to do this.

bash_a.sh:

```
ssh -t -t server-a.com "
cd /var/
irb
..etc
"
```

I was thinking something along the lines:

```
echo "
ssh -t -t server-a.com "
cd /var/
irb
..etc
"
" > /usr/local/bin/bash_a.sh
```

Or this:

```
cp bash_a.sh /usr/local/bin/bash_a.sh
ssh -t -t server-a.com "
cd /var/
irb
..etc
"
```

Comment: Based on the answer you accepted, the title and first paragraph of your question are wrong.  You say you're asking how a script can recreate *itself*, but you accepted an answer to the question, "Given a script *A*, how can I write a script *B* that can create script *A* without needing an additional file to do this?"  Totally different question.  And what does the last paragraph of your question (using `cp` to make a copy of a script file) have to do with any of this?  That's why five people agreed that your question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the single-quotes and double-quotes trick for your suggestion:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
ssh -t -t server-a.com "
cd /var/
irb
..etc
"
' > /usr/local/bin/bash_a.sh
chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/bash_a.sh
```

Inside single quotes, the shell handles the data unchanged.
Inside double quotes, the shell expands $variables, backslash, backticks and all
sorts of stuff. So generally use single quotes where possible.

However, inside single quotes you can't use single quotes easily, whereas
double quotes inside single quotes is easy.

Inside double quotes you **can** use double quotes, but you must escape them with backslash.
So `echo "abc\"def\""` prints `abc"def"`.

Inside double quotes you can use single quotes too, but they dont stop all that expansion.
So `echo "abc'def'"` prints `abc'def'`.

You can use single quotes inside single quotes but you have to type:
`echo 'abc'\''def'\''hij'` which prints `abc'def'hij`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer in [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in):

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
BINDIR=/usr/local/bin
if [[ $DIR != $BINDIR && -w $BINDIR ]]
then
    cp "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" $BINDIR
fi
... rest of script
```

The `if` prevents the script from trying to copy itself it's being run from /usr/local/bin, or if it's being run by a user who doesn't have permission to copy there.